# re{ n,} and re{ n, }

Tags: python, regex

I am learning Regex for Python. I have two slightly different re.search() functions below. The only difference is that I added a space before '}'. Could anyone explain what is causing the difference in results? Thanks!

My codes:

```
import re

print(re.search(r'[0-9]{2,}', '1356C4HJT'))
print(re.search(r'[0-9]{2, }', '1356C4HJT'))
```

Results:

```
<re.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='1356'>
None
```

Comment: Does the second one match the string: `1{2, }`?

Answer (score 4):

Because it is illegal to have space in the quantifier, and it would treat it like it's been shown in the demo, which this expression,

```
[0-9]{2, }
```

would match for instance such strings:

```
0{2, }
1{2, }
2{2, }
3{2, }
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/rL7EXS/1/)

and once you remove the space, then it would pass 2 or more digits:

```
222
22
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/NtlqvY/1/)

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"[0-9]{2, }"
test_str = """
0{2, }
1{2, }
2{2, }
3{2, }
4{2, }
5{2, }
9{2, }
222
22
"""

print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

#### Output

```
['0{2, }', '1{2, }', '2{2, }', '3{2, }', '4{2, }', '5{2, }', '9{2, }']
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/rL7EXS/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/rL7EXS/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.